# Lock cells by active user and owner, not by other users (google script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Locking range by owner is working fine, also other users can lock range cells which have access to edit.

I need the script lock cells by active user and owner, not by other users. And on setting description I had set active user email and row number. It works only on owner, on others not working.

Sorry for my bad English!

[image: screenshot]

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  let range = e.range; //get the range of edited cell
  let row = range.getRow(); //get the row
  let col = range.getColumn(); //get the column 
  let value = e.value; //get the new value of edited cell
  let sheet = range.getSheet(); //get the sheet where edit is made
  let userEmail = Session.getEffectiveUser();

  if(col == 2 && row >= 2 && value == "yaroqli" || value == "yaroqsiz"){    //check the edited cell
    
    var protectedRange = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); //get all protection with type range
    for (var i = 0; i < protectedRange.length; i++) { //loop 
      if (protectedRange[i].getDescription() == userEmail + ' - ' + row) { //row matching
        protectedRange[i].remove(); //remove protection
      }
    }

    let lock_range = `B${row}:J${row}`; //set lock range using row
    let protection = sheet.getRange(lock_range).protect() //set protection
      .setDescription(userEmail + ' - ' + row)  //add description
    let me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    protection.addEditor(userEmail);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors()); //remove editors
    if (protection.canDomainEdit())
     protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }

  else if(col == 2 && row >= 2 && value == null){ //check if the edited cell is empty
    var protectedRange = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE); //get all protection with type range
    for (var i = 0; i < protectedRange.length; i++) { //loop 
      if (protectedRange[i].getDescription() == userEmail + ' - ' + row) { //row matching
        protectedRange[i].remove(); //remove protection
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

If a user has edit access they can lock ranges.

As per the [support article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cwho-can-protect-a-range-or-sheet):

> #### Who can protect a range or sheet
>
> - **If you own a spreadsheet**: You can decide who can change ranges and sheets.
> - **If you can edit a spreadsheet**: You can decide who can edit ranges and sheets but can’t take permissions away from owners.
> - **If you can view or comment on a spreadsheet**: You won't be able to make any changes.

Comment: I'm owner, if I select lock value it will lock and get access for me. But other editor select lock value it will lock and get access for all editors and owner. I need only access for editor and owner

Comment: Я не уверен, что понимаю вопрос. Посмотрите по этой ссылке: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection код под текстом "Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group."